# Why I always get a syntax error in bash script

Tags: bash, command

I have the following function in bash, who was previously in the case part of a switch, but no matter where I put it I always get a syntax error

```
    do_start(){
    if[f $PIDFILE]; then
    echo "supervisord already running: $PIDFILE" exit 1 
    fi
    log_begin_msg "Starting Supervisor daemon manager..."
    start-stop-daemon --start --quiet --pidfile $PIDFILE --exec $SUPERVISORD -- $OPTS || log_end_msg 1
    log_end_msg 0
    }
```

and I get:

```
    runScript.sh: Syntax error: "then" unexpected (expecting "}")
```

I don't know what is going on please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spaces around `[ and ]` are needed and I think you meant `-f` to check if this is a file.

You need to replace:

```
if[f $PIDFILE];
```

by:

```
if [ -f "$PIDFILE" ];
```

OR better (since you're using BASH)

```
if [[ -f "$PIDFILE" ]];
```

Comment: I can't believe that a space could do such damage, thank you!

Comment: Yes BASH/shell syntax is pretty rigid on use of spaces and quotes.